# Matching if() statement to any in a list of strings

Tags: c#, regex

I have C# program in which I need to check if a string matches any in in a list of strings.

Currently my method is:

```
if (Regex.Matches(data, @"String1").Count > 0 || Regex.Matches(data, @"String2").Count > 0 || Regex.Matches(data, @"String3").Count > 0){
    /*Code...*/
}
```

So the point is to see if "data" matches any of the strings.

The program requires me to keep a pretty long list of possible strings and update the list every now and then, so this system is pretty inefficient. What would be a better way?

Comment: Ask yourself if a regex really is the right solution here. Then ask yourself how you can group individual items and perform an operation on each item in said grouping. A collection of items, if you will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try *Linq*:

```
  string[] toFind = new string[] {@"String1", @"String2"};

  if (toFind.Any(item => data.Contains(item))) {
    /*Code...*/
  }
```

If you *have to* use *regular expressions*:

```
  string[] patterns = new string[] {@"String1", @"String2"};

  if (patterns.Any(item => Regex.IsMatch(data, item)) {
    /*Code...*/
  }
```